# GRC GNU Radio Companion freezes after 30 seconds when using USRP

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I am using the GNU Radio Companion 3.6.4.1 in a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a virtual machine on Windows 8.
I dowload a FM TX receiver example code from [OZ9AEC](http://www.oz9aec.net/index.php/gnu-radio/grc-examples) and I run with the Ettus USRP N210. But when I run it, it just run for 30 seconds and then stop the audio and freezes the graphs. The output windows does not show any message.

Someone has any idea of what is the problem? I searched in the internet and I cound not find anything.

Comment: You are asking about an application written by a certain user, not about something distributed with GNURadio. I recommend that you post to the mailing list or write to the author of the application asking for advice.

Comment: Many times this depends on the FFT, lower your refresh rate and probably it will solve your problem.

Comment: It's happening with all codes, not just the code from OZ9AEC. I installed the GNU Radio directly in other computer and it's working normally, without stopping after the 30 seconds.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not relevant for your case, But I also had a similar problem but my problem was because I also had OPENBTS installed in ubuntu 14.04.
After removing it worked fine !!